# Google Chrome - Do Incognito tabs automatically delete if phone runs out of battery?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

so recently, I was looking through some personal information on another friends Galaxy s4 (running Kit Kat) when the battery went out. Problem was, I was using incognito mode.

My question is, if there are incognito tabs running and the phone runs out of battery, once it is switched on again, does it still re-open the incognito tabs?

Much appreciated,
Jacob

Answer (score 1):

The very purpose of having an Incognito mode would be beaten if those tabs would come back after you restart the Chrome or the device.

Google has the following to say [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en):

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

> If you **don’t want Google Chrome to save a record** of what you visit and download, you can browse the web in incognito mode.
>
> ...
>
> Incognito mode opens a new window where you can **browse the Internet without Chrome saving the sites you visit.**... When you close the tabs, Chrome won’t save the sites you’ve visited.

When browsing in Incognito mode Chrome doesn't record the tabs you visit which means there exists no possibility for a normal user to retrieve  them if the Chrome tries to recover/resume the last browsing session once you boot the device after charging it, in your case.

Whatever you browsed in that mode before the device went dark is lost now.

Though having a clear proof already,  I did test the solution by crashing my device and then launching the Chrome after booting it. Nope, those tabs doesn't show up anywhere.